How to validate booleans when importing a csv using ChoETL?
I built a tool for users to import CSVs and create custom column mappings for the import. It uses the ChoETL csv tool to parse the CSV. I'm adding some boolean columns and I'm not sure how to validate the data to make sure that the values provided fit the ChoETL default setting, ChoBooleanFormatSpec.ZeroOrOne.
Ideally, I would want to simply throw an exception (to be returned as a nice message) if the type isn't correct. But when I tried putting "True" instead of a 1, ChoETL parsed it as false. How can I do this?
According to the documentation you can only choose one supported format.

Cinchoo ETL implicitly handles parsing/writing of boolean CSV column values from CSV files. If you want to fine control the parsing of these values, you can specify them globally via ChoTypeConverterFormatSpec.BooleanFormat. Default value is ChoBooleanFormatSpec.ZeroOrOne.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1155891/Cinchoo-ETL-CSV-Writer#20.4%C2%A0BooleanSupport41

Please quote the releveant section. Linking to it would be an optional add-on but questions should be self-contained. (or at least as self-contained as possible)

Asking "What is the most elegant way to do this?" will get you closed in no-time for being opinion-based. "Elegance" really lies in the eye of the beholder and therefore is inherently subjective. Better ask for "a" way to do it. Then you can choose from the provided answers which you find most "elegant". Most users will not intentionally post crooked, convoluted and /or ugly solutions.

Request for information: Are you using any CSV Helper Lib or are you rolling your own? If the latter: I'd recommend you switch to the former.

It is an issue with bool converter, defaulting to false for incorrect values. applied fix. released nuget package v1.2.1.67
    string csv = @"Id, Name, IsActive
1, Tom, 0
2, Mark, 1
3, Shelly, true";

    using (var r = ChoCSVReader<EmployeeC>.LoadText(csv)
           .WithFirstLineHeader()
           .TypeConverterFormatSpec(ts => ts.BooleanFormat = ChoBooleanFormatSpec.ZeroOrOne)
          )
    {
        r.Print();
    }

Sample fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BR4a55

Thank you! The default boolean format is True/False, not Zero/One like it says in the documentation so that needs to be updated. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1145337/Cinchoo-ETL-CSV-Reader#:~:text=Default%20value%20is%C2%A0ChoBooleanFormatSpec.ZeroOrOne
Also, is there a way to customize the error message?
